# Overlapping vdb artifacts don't appear in cycles viewport but do appear in cycles render v3.6 LTS

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

I use blender for scientific visualization. Lately I've been leveraging openvdb to load and render voxel models as volumes. Some of my workflows involve overlapping volumes, and there have been well-known and well-reported "blocky artifacts" associated with overlapping volumes ever since blender began supporting volumes. I've recently moved to 3.6 and to my surprise the artifacts don't appear in the viewport, but they do still appear in Cycles renders.  The discrepancy between viewport and render is surprising - is it a bug, or are there viewport-/render- specific settings that I've missed?

Here's the viewport:
[image: viewport of overlapping vdb models]

And here's the render:
[image: render of overlapping cdv models]

The artifacts in the render are typical of overlapping volumes in previous blender versions, but I used to encounter them in the viewport as well.

I'll note that I have seen significant performance gains without quality losses for my specific application by increasing the new /render/volumes/Step Rate, but I have them set the same for the viewport and render:

[image: My Render Tab / Volumes / Step Rate settings]

Thanks in advance!